# Comos DB order by result from function

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have created a function that display the _ts as friendly. But I would like to order that result. Something like:

SELECT udf.convertTime(c._ts) as d FROM c order by c.d

Is this not possible?

```
function convertTime(unix_timestamp){

      var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var month = ("0"+(date.getMonth()+1)).substr(-2);
      var day = ("0"+date.getDate()).substr(-2);
      var hour = ("0"+date.getHours()).substr(-2);
      var minutes = ("0"+date.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
      var seconds = ("0"+date.getSeconds()).substr(-2);


      return year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+hour+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
}
```

Comment: can you post the UDF

Comment: Done. Added to original post.

Comment: I think `c._ts` and `c.d` are essentially the same, and they can also be sorted.
`SELECT udf.convertTime(c._ts) as d FROM c  order by c._ts (DESC/ASC)`

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Have you found a better solution?

Comment: Yes it worked. Can you post an answer?

Comment: @ThomasSegato You are so kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially `c._ts` and `c.d` are the same, so you can use the following statement to query.

```
SELECT udf.convertTime(c._ts) as d FROM c  order by c._ts (DESC/ASC)
```